# Получить значение метки внутри контейнера

Tags: docker, devops

Каким образом работают метки в `docker`? Чтобы конкретизировать вопрос, я приведу пример.

```
version: '3'
services:
  flask:
    build: ./flask
    image: flask
    command: uwsgi --http-socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --wsgi-file app.py --callable app
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=flask"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=${TRAEFIK_FRONTEND_RULE}"
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v1.7.24
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml:ro
      - ./traefik/acme:/etc/traefik/acme
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"
     - "8080:8080"
```

В `traefik` мы видим метки. Каким образом приложение внутри контейнера **traefik** узнаёт о метках. А самое главное, почему используются метки, а не переменные окружения? Какие задачи они выполняют?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, метки нужны для того, чтобы легче управлять сущностями в docker. Т.е. выполнять такие задачи, как поиск контейнеров или сетей, когда их много. А не для того, чтобы передавать параметры внутрь контейнера.

Поясню на примере. Допустим есть приложение, которое состоит из трех контейнеров: `web-ui`, `backend`, `storage`. И допустим его запускают для 10 клиентов, т.е. у нас для каждого клиента запущено три контейнера.

Было бы удобно для каждого контейнера типа X (где Х одно из `web-ui`, `backend`, storage) создать метки:

1. `component=X`
2. `customer=customerY`

Тогда удобно делать команды

"показать все контейнеры клиента XYZ":

```
docker ps --filter "label=customer=XYZ"
```

Или показать все контейнеры типа `backend`:

```
docker ps --filter "label=component=backend"
```

Метки можно использовать не только для контейнеров, но и для образов, сетей и [других сущностей](https://docs.docker.com/config/labels-custom-metadata/).

`traefik` это сервис, который маршрутизирует запросы извне к соответствующим контейнерам. Он использует метки на контейнерах для этой маршрутизации. По сути с помощью меток задается конфигурация маршрутизации.

Эту конфигурацию можно было бы задать и с помощью переменных окружения `traefik`. Но конфигурация с использованием меток имеет некоторые преимущества:

1. Проще искать контейнеры, которые находятся под управлением `traefik`.
2. Конфигурация с помощью переменных окружения статична, и каждый запуск/останов контейнеров, потребует перезапуска контейнера `traefik`. Метки же привязаны к контейнеру. Если контейнер остановить - то и соответствующая конфигурация автоматически пропадает. А чтоб изменить конфигурацию достаточно перезапустить контейнер с указанием новых значений меток (а в [будущем](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21721) вероятно появится возможность просто изменить метку).

Приложение из traefik получает метки с других запущенных контейнеров обращаясь к сервису docker используя API, которое docker предоставляет.

Comment: Да, мне тоже показалось это очень странным и абсолютно не ясно, для чего это сделано. Я про вызовы АПИ. Спасибо.

Comment: `Пример из вопроса назначает метки для образа который собирается из ./flask/Dockerfile`

это не так - есть label на образе, есть label на контейнере - и это разные сущности

Comment: `Если метки используются таким образом для передачи параметров конфигурации приложению ..., то это очень спорный дизайн, т.к. приложение traefik зависит от docker API без видимой необходимости.`

это очень спорное утверждение, т.к. именно указание конфигурации _инфраструктурного_ сервиса traefik через метки контейнеров - очень осмысленно. Подчеркну - не сервиса flask (которому его параметры должны прийти из окружения согласно 12factor). Зачем так сделано?  traefik слушает сокет докера и перестраивает конфигурацию роутинга http в зависимости от новых запущенных сервисов, в динамике

Comment: Вы правы, не знал про сущность `traefik`, а тут это важно. В оправдание скажу, что это как раз попадает в оговорку `если нет особых причин сделать иначе`, а инфраструктурность `traefik` как раз и есть такая причина. Дополнил ответ в этой части.